# spring core version updation in spring boot parent starter 1.5.10.RELEASE

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven-3, spring-io, maven-bom

Here is the maven dependency I have

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

what I'm trying to achieve is, change the spring core from 4.3.14.RELEASE to 4.3.4.RELEASE. Yes, by default spring boot starter, is using spring core 4.3.14 which can be extended to 5.0.7.RELEASE  for that I tried excluding spring-core and including with 4.3.4.RELEASE

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
                <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
       <dependency>
               <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
               <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
               <version>4.3.4.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

When i tried to build it throws the following expection

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setFilterChainProxySecurityConfigurer' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.convert.support.DefaultConversionService.getSharedInstance()Lorg/springframework/core/convert/ConversionService;
```

Manually adding each and every dependency is not possible because the application is using a hell lot of dependencies and compatibility with other dependencies would be another tough job.

So is there any workaround for this?

**NOTE**:- tried to work with spring framework-bom and spring IO and yet didn't find any solution maybe I missing something. Examples of those are welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't really do this. Spring Framework > Spring Boot > Spring Cloud > Data Flow all manage these dependencies for a reason. You should let spring handle the dependnecies and upgrade your implementations as needed.

https://spring.io/blog/2016/04/13/overriding-dependency-versions-with-spring-boot

Answers this in more detail.

> It is a reasonable thing to want to do this, but it should be done
>   with caution, because newer versions of transitive dependencies can
>   easily break features that rely on the older version in Spring
>   Boot. When you do this, and apply one of the fixes below, you are
>   divorcing yourself from the dependency management of Spring Boot and
>   saying “hey, I know what I am doing, trust me.” Unfortunately,
>   sometimes you need to do this in order to take advantage of new
>   features in third party libraries. If you don’t need the new version
>   of Reactor (or whatever other external transitive dependency you
>   need), then don’t do this, just stick to the happy path and let Spring
>   Boot manage the dependencies.